# How to make nice UI in Ruby Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface

Are there special libraries or packages or frameworks for Ruby that help in creating a nice looking layout on the views (web pages)?

What are some good technologies, tools and general patterns for handling the presentation layer in Ruby on Rails based applications?

Comment: You mean you want like .css file with pretty buttons and stuff.

Comment: @Alex I mean more of - do people use a separate CMS that controls UI layouts, or are there some tools that help keep the UI-layer code organized and modular? Since I am using RoR, it would obviously be better to find some tools that lend themselves well to RoR development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.html5rocks.com/

This is not a ruby problem.  Ruby on Rails applications simply deliver HTML, JS and CSS like any other website.  Creating nice looking pages and interfaces is not something Ruby or Rails try to solve at all, it's kind of an unrelated problem.

That said, there are a few ruby tools to make working in html and css easier.  HAML and SASS for example, provide a more abstracted way to write HTML and CSS.  But understanding of the fundamentals of web development from the browser's point of view is still critical to making stuff that looks nice.

But there is currently no "install this library to make things look nice".  And most would argue that there should not be such a library.

Comment: @Squeegy I realize it is an unrelated problem in general, but generally there tend to be some preferred and proven ways of doing this that work better than others.

Comment: Well you specifically ask about ruby.  If your question is simply "How do I make beautiful web pages", then the answer is "go learn to design and to use CSS".  Ruby has little to do with it.  The question is too vague for SO to provide more help than that.

Comment: @Squeegy Not sure you are completely right.  It is less of a cut and dry topic.  I mean, I could use Drupal or something, but that would create a whole bunch of awkwardness with the PHP layer and Ruby, which I would not want.  Maybe using a UI framework native to Ruby would make life much easier in creating the UI layer.  Do you see what I am saying?

Comment: @Squeegy By the way, the examples on the link you provided are really cool lol - wondering how much of a learning curve there is in HTML5 for traditional backend programmers who tinker with UI just a little bit.

Comment: I do see what you are saying, but the "framework" you refer to is HTML + CSS.  The other answers mention blueprint and compass, which are very handy, but you still need to understand HTML and CSS to use them.  The reason what you want doesn't really exist is because it turns out it's not very useful.  You end up with something very generic.  Abstracting that out only sacrifices control over how things look, and the only gain not having to learn another kind fo thing.  But you should learn it, because that's the right way to do it.

Comment: @Squeegy So do you recommend I just write the HTML essentially by hand and?  Can you give an example of maybe how you set up the presentation of your own projects?  I am just trying to get my head around a viable way of making it all play nice together. - Thanks!

Comment: Yes, write the HTML by hand, _always_. There really isn't any magic in "setting up the presentation". If you want to dive into web design, start with a simple static site (no Rails).  There are countless sites and books out there on putting simple HTML + CSS sites together.  The techniques in Rails are really the same, with the difference that a portion of the HTML on each page is dynamic instead of pulled form a static file.  But the fundamentals are exactly the same. I think most of your confusion on this subject is just a lack of understanding of the most basic browser level web technology.

Comment: @Squeegy, +1 on everything. "I think most of your confusion on this subject is just a lack of understanding of the most basic browser level web technology." I sense that too. Rails, Sinatra, or any MVC requires *someone* in the development team to understand HTML and CSS at more than an introductory level. Rails and their ilk ease the developer's burden when it comes to directing requests and sending the correct output for those requests, but they do little to generate a UI, especially a pretty one. That is the web designer's task. We should all have a passing idea of how it works though.

Comment: @Squeegy @the Tin Man But then there is a fundamental question of scalability of page management.  What I mean is, lets say you have 100 pages which are all made by hand, and if you have to make some change, you have to go through the 100 pages and edit them.  And then a week later same thing..and a week later same thing. It may even be ok for a 100-page site, but what about sites with 1000s of pages?

Comment: @Genadinik well that example is where Rails _does_ help you out. First you have the idea of templates rather than pages. A user, for instance, may have a "page" and you may have millions of users, but you only need one template that all user pages come from.  Also rails provides layouts which hold common page structure around your content (like header, footer, menus, css/js includes, etc).  And if multiple views have shared HTML that can't be in a layout, then you can use Rails partials and helpers. This is all built right into Rails.

Comment: @Squeegy Yes this type of information was what I was really after.  I think I just didn't know how to ask it right.  Is there a tutorial for specifically setting up the Ruby UI templates in the right way? - Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik Any beginner Rails book/tutorial would probably go over view templates, layouts, partials and helpers. Those are pretty fundamental features of the framework.  Note you still write your own CSS and HTML, you just write it smart and dynamic instead of static.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). Nice framework to manage you css.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ruby specific but the [blueprint css framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is helpful for establishing grid, typography, browser, form elements, css reset and more. From there it's fairly easy to style your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

what about [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)?